# Javascript RegExp as property

Tags: javascript, regex

Why can't I do such thing?

```
var obj = {
    prop1:"a",
    prop2:"b",
    test1: new RegExp(this.prop1),
    test2: new RegExp(this.prop2),
    init: function(){
            if(this.test1.test('apple')){
                //code will be executed
            }
            if(this.test1.test('banana')){
               //code will be executed
            }
            if(this.test2.test('apple')){
               //code will be executed
            }
            if(this.test2.test('banana')){
               //code will be executed
            }
   }
};
obj.init();
```

Test will always return true, because it is `/(?:)/`. How to fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/jk8MK/

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? What is your question ?

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? What is your question ? buddy

Comment: @Neel Oh, I missed `buddy` haha

Comment: yes buddy @crypticous :DD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use function instead:

```
var obj = {
   prop1:"a",
   prop2:"b",
   test1: function()
   {
       return new RegExp(this.prop1);
   },
   test2: function()
   {
       return new RegExp(this.prop2);
   },
   init: function(){
           if(this.test1().test('apple')){
               console.log('1');
           }
           if(this.test1().test('banana')){
               console.log('2');
           }
           if(this.test2().test('apple')){
               console.log('3');
           }
           if(this.test2().test('banana')){
               console.log('4');
           }
   }
};
obj.init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jk8MK/2/

Comment: And the way to save test1 and test2 as a property is to make them null in obj, and then assign regexp in init() function...

Comment: or if you don't need test1/2 as object property, you can use just local variable: http://jsfiddle.net/jk8MK/3/

Answer (score 2):

Okay I must tell you whats happening inside : the string contained in prop1 is not available for the RegExp part so the regex formed is `//` which can match both apple and banana